# Beginner - image without background

Tags: delphi

I try to make an interactive map:

[image]

There is only one area on each `TImage`, loaded with a `.png` image.

How to make an `OnClick` or `OnMouseEnter` event handler when I chose any province?

Comment: I take it that you have a multiple TImage controls on top of each other?  Only the top one (that has `HitTest` set) will respond to a mouse click.
Assuming that each .png/province is a unique colour, then handling a MouseUp event (for whatever control responds) by using the mouse coordinates to check each .png pixel colour may be about the only way to go.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `HitTest` property.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You're half right.  For some reason I assumed Firemonkey, which does have a `HitTest` property.  But if the poster is referring to VCL, which I guess is likely, you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

`OnMouse(Down|Up|Move)` events give you coordinates of the mouse relative to the top-left corner of the `TImage`'s client area at the time of the event.

`OnClick` and `OnMouse(Enter|Leave)` events do not provide any coordinates, but you can use the Win32 API [`GetMessagePos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagepos) function to discover the screen coordinates of the mouse at the time of those events, and then convert them into relative client coordinates using the `TImage`'s `ScreenToClient()` method.